# How to search in UITableview which have multi section in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

My `UITableView` have 2 section are *"Local currency"* and *"All currencies"*.

No problem when I search and both section return results. But when I search and return results only within section 2 then no cell in section *"All currencies"* be displayed. It 's just only display header of *"Local currency"* with 0 cell.

I want to when I search if which section no have in result then this header of its session will be hidden and just which secion have result will be display header and its content.

This is my code and `searchResultsLocal,searchResultsPopular` are the two results `NSArray` when I search:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //if (searchResultsLocal.count > 0 && searchResultsPopular.count > 0) {
    //    return 2;
    //}
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return [searchResultsLocal count];
    }
    return searchResultsPopular.count;
}
```

Ay help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code where you get the result of search key and reduce the `searchResultsLocal `/`searchResultsLocal `

Comment: Plz post code for your searching logic

Answer (score 0):

Tks u so much.I have figure out solution :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 20;
}
```